# Rename Class without Renaming Companion Object?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, refactoring

Is it possible to rename a Scala class without renaming the companion object of the same name using IntelliJ's refactoring facilities? If not, does some other IDE support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `XXX` to the name of the companion object, rename the class, take `XXX` off the name of the object.

Answer (score 3):

You may rename class without companion object by disabling the option "Rename companion object" at class rename:
[image]